# Why Scikit GradientBoostingClassifier won't let me use least squares regression?

Tags: python, data-mining, scikit-learn

Why could it be that

```
GradientBoostingClassifier(loss='ls')
```

fails with:

```
raise ValueError("``n_classes`` must be 1 for regression")
ValueError: ``n_classes`` must be 1 for regression
```

and it works perfectly with `loss='deviance'`?

I'm using scikit-learn-0.11 with scipy-0.11.0rc1 in Ubuntu 64 bits
This happened classifying a dataset with binary class 'YES' 'NO'.

Comment: Because least squares regression is for regression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) and the gradient boosting classifier is for classification (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_in_machine_learning)?

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug in `GradientBoostingClassifier`. It shouldn't expose the least squares loss function for classification. Please use the "deviance" loss function instead.

Sorry for the inconveniences caused.

PS: If you really need least squared loss for classification please contact me and we can work on this feature for a future release.

Comment: Opened an issue for this: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1085

Comment: The issue has been fixed in release 0.12